# Get last record offset in kafka partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, offset

I want to get the last record offset in the topic partition. There is `endOffsets` method in the consumer. And usually `endOffsets - 1` works fine. But in the case of transactional producer topic may contain offsets without a records. And `endOffsets - 1` will point to the offset without record. So, how should I compute the last record offset in this case?

More interestingly, what if I will have both a simple and transactional producer for my topic? Is there any reliable way to get the last record offset ignoring all this complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up realizing that there is no reliable and simple way to do that in the current version of the java consumer. I created a feature request for that in Kafka's issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10009